# A bag containing counters each with a different currency value

Tags: probability

A bag contains 10 counters labelled 1 to 10. The first 6 are worth £1 each, the next 2 are worth £5 each, the next one is worth £10 and the final one is worth £50. You draw a counter from the bag at random. Its value being X pounds.
Let $\Omega= \lbrace1,2,\dots,10\rbrace$.

The questions are as follows:

1. Write down the function corresponding to a random variable X, i.e, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, write down $X(\omega)$
2. What subset of $\Omega$ does the event $\lbrace X \leq 5 \rbrace$ correspond to? Find $\mathbb{P}\lbrace X \leq 5 \rbrace$
3. Write down the probability mass function *p* of *X*, i.e. write down in a table all values *X* can take and their corresponding probabilities.
4. Use the probability mass function to find $\mathbb{P} (X \geq 10)$

So for question one I have no idea what to do, the notation confuses me honestly and I think maybe that's why I'm stuck.

For question 2. I believe the subset would be $A = \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \rbrace$ and I believe the probability is 0.8.

Again for number 3 I'm unsure what to do, do I simply write a table with $1,2,\dots,10$ in one row and then underneath for the probability just simply put $\frac{1}{10}$ for each counter. If this is the case what do I put in the tables as the titles? For the probability one would it be $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ ?

Finally for number 4 is it just 0.2.

On an unrelated note, I'm struggling with interpreting notation while reading my lecturers notes for probability, will this improve over time just with practice. Or is there anywhere else I can look for additional help on mathematical notation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to the second and fourth questions are correct.

The elements $\omega \in \Omega$ are the counters $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$.  The values $X(\omega)$ are the values of the counters.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
X(\omega) & = 1~\text{pound}, ~\text{if}~1 \leq \omega \leq 6\\
X(\omega) & = 5~\text{pounds}, ~\text{if}~7 \leq \omega \leq 8\\
X(\omega) & = 10~\text{pounds}, ~\text{if}~\omega = 9\\
X(\omega) & = 50~\text{pounds}, ~\text{if}~\omega = 10
\end{align*}

As for the probability mass function, we want to find the probability that the value of the counter is equal to a particular value for each possible value of $X$.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X = 1~\text{pound}) & = 0.6\\
\Pr(X = 5~\text{pounds}) & = 0.2\\
\Pr(X = 10~\text{pounds}) & = 0.1\\
\Pr(X = 50~\text{pounds}) & = 0.1
\end{align*}